# Can someone help me to translate this line of code for bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have been struggling to understand this line of code, could someone helpe me ?

for what I understood the od means will convert the outout for octal format, -An I think it means input base which is no address but why ?
and the -N is the length

if someone could help to translate this while sintax I would appreciate

```
n=$((`od -An -N1 -i /dev/random` %100 ))
```

Comment: This works for me in bash (and ksh, and both them invoked as sh), so syntactically it seems OK, there's no need to "translate" it to bash per se. Maybe it doesn't do what you want but then we'd need to know what you want it to do in order to help you.

Comment: @stickybit: IIUC, OP doesn't wan to translate this line to Bash, they want to understand what it means.

Comment: Better written `n=$((RANDOM % 100))` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`od -An -N1 -i /dev/random` takes one byte (`-N1`) of input from `/dev/random`, treats it as a signed integer value (`-i`) and uses no address base (`-An`) (this is done to disable the header line od usually outputs). Running just this will give you a random number between 0 and 255.

Putting this command in backticks "`" places od's output into the commandline.

`$((x % y))` calculates x modulo y, where x is od's output and y is 100 in your example.

Finally, the result is placed in the variable `n` which you can access by using e.g. `echo $n`

Comment: I really appreciate!! Its was what I was looking for, thank your very much!!